# How to keep comments in this AWK command

Tags: bash, awk

I have a zipped file. I want to split it into multiple files by the first column. The command below does that but it's also skipping comments. How do I include the header/comments `#` in the output? Also, I would like to save the output as "[the value in column 1].vcf". How do I do that?

```
zcat 1000G.vcf.gz | awk '!/^#/{print>$1}'
```

Sample 1000G.vcf

```
# header 1
# header 2
# header 3
1    A    B
1    C    B
1    C    D
2    A    B
2    C    D
2    C    E
3    A    B
3    B    D
```

I want the awk command to create 3 vcf files:

1.vcf

```
# header 1
# header 2
# header 3
1    A    B
1    C    B
1    C    D
```

2.vcf

```
# header 1
# header 2
# header 3
2    A    B
2    C    D
2    C    E
```

3.vcf

```
# header 1
# header 2
# header 3
3    A    B
3    B    D
```

Comment: What file should the comment lines be put into?

Comment: Remove **^#** from the awk command.

Comment: @ArifBurhan Then it will create files with `#` in the filename.

Comment: @ArifBurhan. what Barmar said is correct. It'll create files with `#` in the filename. I want to name the output by the value in column 1 but I also want to keep the comments/header.

Comment: Edit your question to include concise, testable sample input (to the awk command) and expected output so we can start to try to help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your second question, you can concatenate the extension to the column 1 value.

```
awk '!/^#/ { file = $1 ".vcf"; print > file } '
```

For the header lines, append them to a variable. The first time you write to a file, write the comments to it.

```
awk '/^#/ { comments = comments ? comments "\n" $0 : $0 ; next }
     !files[$1] { file = $1 ".vcf"; print comments > file; files[$1] = 1 }
     { file = $1 ".vcf"; print > file }'
```

Comment: Do you know how I keep the comments/headers (`#`) in the output?

Comment: You never answered my question above. Where should it get the filename for comment lines?

Comment: The filenames shouldn't have comment lines in them. I want to keep the comment lines in every output file. The filename for every output file should only be the [value of column 1].vcf, and in every output file the comments/header (`#`) should be the same.

Comment: The same as **what**? Column 1 from the line before it? What if the first line is a comment?